# If do_shortcode is blank, return some message

Tags: shortcode

I have a page for employment postings. To expire the posts, I'm using the PostExpirator plugin with the shortcode, [postexpirator]. If not expiration date is selected within the plugin, I'd like to return the message "UNTIL FILLED."

Here is the code I have working so far.

````
echo '<div class="entry-content">';
echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" class="block-link">';

echo '<header class="one-half first entry-header block-link-entry-header">';
echo '<p>' . get_the_title() . '</p>';
echo '</header>';

echo '<p class="one-half">';
echo do_shortcode( '[postexpirator]' );
echo '</p>';
echo '</a>';
echo '<hr>';
echo '</div>';

echo '</article>';```
````

Comment: possibly ask in the support forum of your plugin https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/post-expirator/

Answer (score -1):

From several version of WordPress, it's better to use https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_shortcodes/ io `do_shortcode`.

That said you can surely do something using `has_shortcode()` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_shortcode/

Comment: Why is that better? And it sounds like the goal of the question is to run the shortcode but change the text output, so I don't think has_shortcode() will help.